# python don't extract zipfile when ran through crontab

Tags: python, cron, ubuntu-16.04

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests, zipfile, StringIO, sys
extractDir = "myfolder"
zip_file_url = "download url"
response = requests.get(zip_file_url)
zipDocument = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(response.content))
zipinfos = zipDocument.infolist()
for zipinfo in zipinfos:
    extrat = zipDocument.extract(zipinfo,path=extractDir)
```

System configuration

1. Ubuntu OS 16.04
2. Python 2.7.12

`$ python extract.py`
 when I run the code on Terminal with above command, it works properly and create the folder and extract the file into it.

Similarly, when I create a cron job using sodu rights the code executes but don't create any folder or extracts the files.

crontab command:-

```
40 10 * * * /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/demo/directory.py > /home/ubuntu/demo/logmyshit.log 2>&1
```

also tried

```
40 10 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/demo/directory.py > /home/ubuntu/demo/logmyshit.log 2>&1
```

Notes :

1. I check the syslog, it says the cron is running successfully
2. The above code gives no errors
3. also made the python program executable by chmod +x filename.py

Please help where am I going wrong.

Comment: Does the cron job correctly write to your `logmyshit.log` file?

Comment: Why do you attempt to run this with `sudo`? Are you sure there are no errors in the log file you write?

Comment: What is the contents and date of your `logmyshit.log` file?

Comment: @lxop when I print something it writes that to my log file

Comment: @tripleee I ran this with sudo to confirm the program is running with root user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups, there is nothing really wrong in running a Python script in crontab, but many bad things can happen because the environment is not the one you are used to.

When you type in an interactive shell `python directory.py`, the PATH and all required PYTHON environment variable have been set as part of login and interactive shell initialization, and the current directory is your home directory by default or anywhere you currently are.

When the same command is run from crontab, the current directory is not specified (but may not be what you expect), PATH is only `/bin:/usr/bin` and python environment variables are not set. That means that you will have to tweak environment variables in crontab file until you get a correct Python environment, and set the current directory.

Comment: your suggestion **set the current directroy** worked for me 
i just added  `os.chdir(path)` before my directory gets created and solved my problem. 
Thank you every one.

Comment: @JayeshPatil: If you need no longer help here, you should mark one of the answer as *accepted*.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and it turned out cron didn’t like importing matplotlib, I ended up having to specify Agg backend.  I figured it out by putting log statements after each line to see how far the program got before it crapped out.  Of course, my log was empty which tipped me off that it crashed on imports.

TLDR: log each line inside the script

Comment: Your proposed fix is pretty specific to matplotlib, though. The OP uses only system libraries apart from `requests`, and nothing which requires a GUI.

Comment: I guess my point was to log each line to hopefully see where it breaks.  My bet is some weird cron system path behavior with the imports.

Comment: @Fraxr I tried your approach too, printed each line of my code still no error

Comment: Also try stripping out one imported library at a time to see which one chokes it.